# PageSpeed Insights ошибка при тестировании

Tags: pagespeed-insights, pagespeed

При попытке просканировать сайт http://izba.ixweb.ru/ выдается ошибка и не сканирует его вовсе, в чем может быть проблема?

Lighthouse returned error: INTERNAL: Extension result empty. Lighthouse calling Page.navigate with http://izba.ixweb.ru/ Uncaught (in promise) Error: Extension timed out. No call to exit() before render timeout. at wrs.Extension.onTimeout_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:5567:13) at http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:669:9 at Map.forEach () at chromium.DevTools.Connection.dispatchMessage (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:668:76) at chromium.DevTools.Connection.onJsonMessage_ (http://ghost-rider/devtools_script_api.js:650:65) at :1:40

Answer (score 0):

> При попытке просканировать сайт http://izba.ixweb.ru/...

Указанный вами урл есть субдомен, но не веб-сайт. Веб-сайт имеет следующий **[урл](http://ixweb.ru/)**, который, в свою очередь, имеет **[две проблемы связанные с ДНС](https://intodns.com/ixweb.ru)**:

> **Missing nameservers reported by parent**
>
> FAIL: The following nameservers
>   are listed at your nameservers as nameservers for your domain, but are
>   not listed at the parent nameservers (see RFC2181 5.4.1). You need to
>   make sure that these nameservers are working.If they are not working
>   ok, you may have problems! ns1.beget.com ns2.beget.ru ns1.beget.ru
>   ns2.beget.com
>
> **Stealth NS records sent**
>
> Stealth NS records were sent: ns1.beget.com ns2.beget.ru ns1.beget.ru
>   ns2.beget.com

Эти же самые проблемы имеют действие и на ваш субдомен также.

Кроме того ваш **[суб-домен имеет следующую проблему](https://sitecheck.sucuri.net/results/izba.ixweb.ru)**:

> Site Issue 405 Not Allowed

Более подробно о этой проблеме вы можете читать в документации Mozilla MDN **[405 Method Not Allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405)**:

> Код состояния протокола HTTP  405 Method Not Allowed, указывает, что
>   метод запроса известен серверу, но был отключен и не может быть
>   использован.

Вероятно вам надо контактировать с владельцем домена и, совместно с ним и провайдером хостинга, решать эти проблемы.